# how to append to list below example given and output also?

Tags: javascript, python, django

This is the data:

```
data=[{"id":1,"name":"vikash","roll":39},{"id":2,"name":"kumar","roll":3}] 

data2=[{"hobby":"football","food":"any"},{"hobby":"basketball","food":"any"}]
list1=[]
```

expected Output:

```
list1:[{"name":"vikash","roll":39,"hobby":"football","food":"any"},{"name":"kumar","roll":3,"hobby":"basketball","food":"any"}]
```

Please help me!

Comment: Hi, the result is needed in what Language? Javascript or Python?

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is not enough information here to provide a definitive answer [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Providing both lists are the same length, you're happy there are no key conflicts and you're using Python...

```
data=[{"id":1,"name":"vikash","roll":39},{"id":2,"name":"kumar","roll":3}]

data2=[{"hobby":"football","food":"any"},{"hobby":"basketball","food":"any"}]


list1 = []

for k, v in enumerate(data):
    list1.append({**v, **data2[k]})

print(list1)
```

However in the future please be more concise when asking your questions.

- Specify the language
- Don't include redundant tags (eg - this question has nothing to do with Django)
- Tell us what you've tried!

Also... the "please help me" line isn't required. The whole purpose of this community is to help each other so again this is redundant!

Answer (score 0):

**A simpler to understand solution**

```
data=[{"id":1,"name":"vikash","roll":39},{"id":2,"name":"kumar","roll":3}] 

data2=[{"hobby":"football","food":"any"},{"hobby":"basketball","food":"any"}]
list1=[]


for i in range(len(data)):
    del data[i]['id']
    d_main = {}
    d_main.update(data[i])
    d_main.update(data2[i])
    list1.append(d_main)
    
print(list1)
```